# git hook getting changeset after an auto commit

Tags: git, githooks, changeset

I have a hook that takes the changed files and copies them to a directory it works for standard commits but the auto-commit of a merge breaks it as the last two commits doesn't contain any changed files

Here is my current code

```
generateChangeSet() {
    if [ ! -d $WORKDIR ];then
        mkdir $WORKDIR
    fi

    CHANGESET=$(git log -1 --name-status $oldrev $newrev | grep -v -e "^Merge" -e "^commit" -e "^Author" -e "^Date" -e "^ " -e "^$")
    if [ -z $CHANGESET ]; then
      echo Could not detect any files in the change set, aborting push
      exit $RETVAL
    fi

    # Get a list of deleted files
    DELFILES=$WORKDIR/deletedFiles.sh
    if [ -f $DELFILES ];then
        rm -rf $DELFILES
    fi

    for dFile in $(echo $CHANGESET | grep "^D" | awk '{print $2}'); do
        echo deleted file $dFile
        echo rm -f $dFile >> $DELFILES
    done
    if [ -f $DELFILES ];then
        sed -i '1s/^/#!\/bin\/bash\n/' $DELFILES
        chmod +x $DELFILES
        echo find . -depth -type d -empty >> $DELFILES
        echo rm deletedFiles.sh >> $DELFILES
    fi

    echo "Generating diff between $newrev and $oldrev"
    git archive HEAD $(echo $CHANGESET | grep -v "^D" | awk '{print $2}') | (cd $WORKDIR && tar xf -)
}
```

Any ideas on how get the script to get the latest changed files at all times?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by being concerned that the target (`$WORKDIR`?) might not be in sync with the delta being computed here in the first place.  Why are deletions being exported through a shell script?  Why not `git checkout` directly into a fresh target (set `GIT_WORK_TREE` to do this), e.g.:

```
what_to_replace=/some/where/tree
tmp_replacement=/some/where/tree.new

rm -rf $tmp_replacement
mkdir $tmp_replacement || fatal "can't create $tmp_replacement"

GIT_WORK_TREE=$tmp_replacement git checkout master -- . ||
    fatal "can't create updated master branch tree"
mv $what_to_replace ${what_to_replace}.old &&
    mv $tmp_replacement $what_to_replace ||
    fatal "can't swap in $tmp_replacement"
rm -rf ${what_to_replace}.old ||
    warn "can't clean up ${what_to_replace}.old"
```

(which probably needs some sort of locking added, and some more fleshing out).  But if you're determined to go on with the existing code (there could be some reason(s) to do so), this part is just silly:

> `CHANGESET=$(git log -1 --name-status $oldrev $newrev | grep -v -e "^Merge" -e "^commit" -e "^Author" -e "^Date" -e "^ " -e "^$")`

Instead, use `git diff-tree --name-status $oldrev $newrev` to diff the trees associated with the given commits.  The rest should be easy.  This all assumes that `$oldrev` accurately reflects the state of whatever's being updated, of course.

Comment: You are right about $WORKDIR being not in sync.  My reason to do this in the first place is that for historical reason source contains hardcoded DB SCHEMAs and my task is until a fix is in place get the code from git to test server and replace DB SCHEMAs with schemas on the test server.  My reason to do it on the changeset is that doing a search and replace on the whole source takes long as there are more than 25k files. The problem I am facing is that the $oldrev doesn't reflect correctly when auto-commits happen e.g after a merge

Comment: Perhaps you should record somewhere ($WORKDIR?) what the last update (via the hook) was.  You can then use `git diff-tree` to compare that rev, instead of `$oldrev` (wherever $oldrev came from—the input to the hook, I assume), against `$newrev`.